# Read another app's DataGridView data

Tags: datagridview

I'm trying to read a DataGridView's values from an application that is not my own. I've managed to get text from edit boxes sending WM_GETTEXT events but the DataGridView doesn't appear to have similar functionality. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an accessibility API [UIAutomation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx). [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/25d6b3a6-1533-4fae-85a7-6cc553c8c9a7) is some code that implements the UI Automation interfaces on the DataGridView control. Hope that helps.

Comment: This pointed me down the right direction. I actually found a project called White which is for automated testing but also works great for just interacting with UIAutomation.